# Route 53 and Cloudfront removing Accept-Ranges: bytes header from s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a strange problem. I'm having a host static hosted on s3, and then the domain is managed by Route 53.

If i request a video from my site via the amazons3 address the response include the Accept-Ranges: bytes header, which I need for smooth video playback.

However, if I access the same resource from the cloudfront distribution, it has all the headers EXCEPT for the Accept-Ranges: bytes header.

Also if I goto the site via a URL that is pointing to the S3 bucket via Route 53, it is ALSO missing the headers.

The only way to get the Accept-Ranges: bytes it seems, is by the direct link to the s3 resource URL.

I would like to distribute the files from cloudfront instead of s3, is there a way to add the Accept-Ranges: bytes header to the cloudfront version of the file (without a lambda function, as that seems over complicated, the entire reason for static hosting is not to have server functions).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront doesn't remove Accept-Ranges header from the response, the reason you are not seeing this header in response because you have S3 static website endpoint as an origin to the CloudFront.

S3 provides 2 endpoints(except transfer acceleration endpoint):

1. REST API endpoint , can be accessed using bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com or s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucket/object
2. S3 static website endpoint accessed as bucket.s3-website.region.amazonaws.com

Both support range request, however, static website endpoint doesn't add Accept-Ranges in the response header but REST API adds it.

You need to select S3 bucket from drop down menu in CLoudFront origin in order to make it correct.

Comment: once made the changes in cloudfront, invalidate the cache in order to make it effect.